# Disable ipad/iphone global gestures using Swift

Tags: ios, exit, gesture, gestures

I am building an app which will be displayed on an iPad. It will be an app for customers in the shop who will be able to leave their contact data. I am going to put an iPad to a frame so they won't be able to press home, lock buttons. Just the screen.

My question is: **is there any way to prevent them from closing my app by a gesture?** (fingers going closer to each other) or a gesture of switching apps? (3 fingers swipe left/right)

I suppose I can set it in settings, but I really need it to be set in the code.
Does iOS system provides that feature (**disabling system gestures programically?**)
Thank you

Comment: You can't do this in code. I suggest that you provide your users with information on configuring their iPad appropriately using either guided access mode or the Apple Configurator tool